# Equatorial Bulge and its implications on the climate

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, geophysics, climate, climate-models

How much of the variance in the climate is due to the equatorial bulge and how much sun radiation do we lose due to the equatorial bulge?

I am interested in the variance both through time and through location.

A more uniform surface would emit/reflect less sun radiation due to Wien's displacement law. As such we would have a higher mean temperature and less variance. I am interested in a quantitative(even if there are no exact numbers) answer and not qualitative.

Comment: The shape also affects the cross section to solar radiation, which  in turn affects the total insolation. With the bulge, I think the cross section is smaller at equinox and greater at solstice.